# Print LevenshteinDistance matrix in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have implemented LevenshteinDistance  algorithm in c# as below.This code is running perfectly.But for debugging purpose I want to print the matrix but not able to decide where should I place the Print statement.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace _Levenshtein_
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Print(int[,] data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < data.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(data[i, j] + " ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        public static int LevenshteinDistance(string source, string target)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target)) return 0;
                {

                    return target.Length;
                }
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(target)) return source.Length;

            if (source.Length > target.Length)
            {
                var temp = target;
                target = source;
                source = temp;
            }

            var m = target.Length;
            var n = source.Length;
            var distance = new int[2, m + 1];
            // Initialize the distance 'matrix'
            for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++) distance[0, j] = j;


                Console.Write(target + " ");

            var currentRow = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
            {
                currentRow = i & 1;
                distance[currentRow, 0] = i;
                var previousRow = currentRow ^ 1;
                Console.WriteLine(source[i-1] + " " );
                for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++)
                {
                    var cost = (target[j - 1] == source[i - 1] ? 0 : 1);

                    distance[currentRow, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(distance[previousRow, j] + 1,distance[currentRow, j - 1] + 1),distance[previousRow, j - 1] + cost);
                    Print(distance);        
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return distance[currentRow, m];
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LevenshteinDistance("Sunday", "Saturday");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to print matix with score at each cell ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:Yes,you are right

Comment: ok I have no C# background so I just shows where to put write string ... WAit ..

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan:It's ok.you can edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added comment to print distance matrix.

```
// `target` string in first ROW, each char in 4 width
// for (var j = 0; j <=target.Length; j++)
//    Console.Write(target[j] + "   ") 
for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
    currentRow = i & 1;
    distance[currentRow, 0] = i;
    var previousRow = currentRow ^ 1;
    // print: `source[i]`  ith char only one Console.Write(source[i] + " ")
    // Console.Write(source[i] + " ") 
    for (var j = 1; j <= m; j++)
    {
        var cost = (target[j - 1] == source[i - 1] ? 0 : 1);
        distance[currentRow, j] = Math.M........);
        // write distance in 3 width
           //Console.Write(distance[currentRow, j] + " ")  
    }       

      // Console.Write("\n")
}
```

**Edit**:

length "Sunday"  = 6
length "Saturday" = 8

```
if (source.Length > target.Length){  // target is large .
    // swap means 
}
```

So target is  "Saturday" string. (Horizontal string)
and "Sunday"   is vertical

You will get output like following fig:
[image]

Here on [**Codepade**](http://codepad.org/04LTcxrS) is my working C code that can print edit-distance matrix like:

```
      S  a  t  u  r  d  a  y  

S     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
u     1  1  2  2  3  4  5  6
n     2  2  2  3  3  4  5  6
d     3  3  3  3  4  3  4  5
a     4  3  4  4  4  4  3  4
y     5  4  4  5  5  5  4  3
```

Comment: What will be the argument for the Print method

Comment: @geek print may not be method I just show where to call printing method you have consol.write.

Comment: @geek Do you want output like this review updated answer ?

Comment: I changed my code as per your instructions but it's not printing correct output

Comment: @geek you missed the distance `distance[currentRow, i];` and new line char

Comment: @geek ok added code as comment in my answer

Comment: I have incorporated all your comments(edited the question),but still I am not getting correct output.if you have solution in any language post it as answer

Comment: @geek see updated answer posted a code working code link : http://codepad.org/04LTcxrS

Comment: @geek Good let me know if you need more help regarding this, specially on C platform